# SED - Change a strings in the line, only if that line start with

Tags: sed

I tried quite a lot of thing and did some search without finding a proper way to do this :

I would like to modify the Apache LogFormat definition on several servers (a lot).
So : within httpd.conf,
replace this:

```
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
```

with this:

```
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %T" combined
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %T" common
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O %T" combinedio
```

without modifying that :

```
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
```

So :
I'm looking to
`s\" com\ %T" com\g'`, but only for lines containing `LogFormat`

And I'm starving to do such a thing.

Comment: Is it the httpd.conf file itself you want to modify, or the output from the log-file before it is consumed by some service?

Comment: the httpd.conf file itself.

Comment: If the conf-file is the same it is maybe easier to change one file and copy this to the servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better served using a dedicated solution such as Ansible for this but using sed, you could do the following:

```
sed -i '/^LogFormat/s/" combined.*$/ %T&/' httpd.conf
```

Search for all lines starting with "LogFormat" and then substitute double quotes, space and "combined" for a space, "%T" and the pattern identified.

Comment: Yeeesss!
I did try something like that but with a (wrong) space before the "s" from substitute.
Thank you for pointing to the solution.
Best regards!